# Unable to post data to the server using NSURLSession, getting NSHTTPURLResponse status code 401

Tags: nsurlsession

Here is my code, I'm getting 401 status code and the data not writing to the server:

```
NSURL *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:@test.com"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request    = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
 [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
self.dictionary =  @{
                     key:Value,
                     key: Value
                     };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data =  [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
request.HTTPBody = data;
else {


NSLog(@"Status code: %li", (long)((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);
       code here //
          };

}];


[postDataTask resume];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error indicates that you didn't provide the proper credentials.  To learn how to do so, read this article from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1

Comment: Thanks so much, i got this fixed.